# How to capture video and audio from camera/webcamera with Xuggle?

Tags: java, video, camera, capture, xuggle

I found out abut [Xuggle](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/) yesterday and let me first say that it is an amazing thing. I run through all of [video](http://wiki.xuggle.com/Tutorials) and [text](http://wiki.xuggle.com/MediaTool_Introduction) tutorials.

My first problem was to programatically record desktop of computer and I solved this [this way](http://wiki.xuggle.com/MediaTool_Introduction#How_To_Take_Snapshots_Of_Your_Desktop).

Now I need something different. I need to capture both audio and video from my camera/webcam and put it into one container.

I would like something like:

1. App detects all cameras that are plugged in
2. I choose from which one of them I want to capture audio and video
3. Encode that audio and video into one container

**Question**: What would be a good starting point or even better if someone has some example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Xuggler author told me, Xuggler lacks good support for capturing video from camera and it is not in it's list of priorities.

My solution is to use vlcj.